# what is different between ObjectFactory and FactoryBean interface in Spring

Tags: java, spring, factory

What is different between `ObjectFactory` and `FactoryBean` interface in `Spring`?
I find `Spring` behavior different with they.

Comment: Read: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectFactory.html

Comment: I read spring document but dont understand that. It means is : `ObjectFactory` return a new instance with any invokation and `FactoryBean` can return a singlton instance?

Answer (score 0):

With `FactoryBean<SomeBean>` as the source of your beans you inject `SomeBean`.
If you have an `ObjectFactory<SomeBean>` you actually inject the `ObjectFactory<SomeBean>` and then explicitly ask it for a bean.